# Can I customize the Gmail missing attachment alerter?

Tags: gmail, attachment

I often forget attachments.  I have the alert on, but I tend to use "Here is the document" instead of a variation of "attach" as in "The document is attached".

Can I add the phrase "here is" to the missing attachment alerter?

Comment: Alternately, you could use "I have included" or "I've included".  I have also posted a new question to find out what *all* of the (default) text string possibilities are: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46729/what-text-triggers-the-gmail-warning-about-forgetting-attachments  I would suggest not saying "Here is" in the first place, though.  Many people would not consider something 'there' unless it is actually in the body of the e-mail.  Maybe GMail is doing us a favour with this little push towards some standardization of this language.  ;)

Comment: If I could remember to use a different string, I would just use "attached" and not have to worry about it!  I'm afraid I'm old and my brain has rotted out!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot customize this yourself.

However, you can ask Google on their Product Forums to add this behavior

See [this thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/gmail/forgot%2420attachments/gmail/THZfRWsnK_0).

Answer (score 0):

I think Gmail's `Email undo` option can be useful in your case, as much as missing attachment is commonly noticed right after you sent an email.

```
Go to Settings.
Click the Labs tab.
Find the "Undo Send" lab and select the Enable radio button.
Click Save Changes at the bottom of the page.
```

[Help page about the subject](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1284885?hl=en)
Hope it helps somehow :)